# Not able to login to WSO2 ESB management console

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have installed WSO2(ESB) version - 4.8.0 following the installation guide(for windows) from the link
http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB480/Downloading+the+Product

I unzip the folder and follow the steps from
http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB480/Running+the+Product

to execute the server. But I am not able to login. It does not show errors and simply shows processing.

Please let me know if there is anything I need to do for using this version.

Thanks,

Sharmistha

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows, go to command window in which you started ESB and press `CTRL + C` to stop the server. OR if you are using Linux and you have put the ESB to background type `sh <PRODUCT_HOME>/bin/wso2server.sh stop` to stop the server.
Close the command window and start the ESB again. Now open the management console again and you will be able to log in.

Answer (score 0):

What is error that you can see in the console? Actually you can just download, unzip ans start the server, Then you are able to login by providing "admin" user name and "admin" password.

Comment: There is no error in the console. The browser keeping rotating the process.I use "admin" as username and password.I follow all the steps as per http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB480/Running+the+Product

Comment: Could you content in the wso2carbon.log file which can be found at <IS_HOME>/repository/logs directory

Comment: Thanks for all your support. I restarted the system and WSO2 seems to be working now. I am able to login. Thanks once again.